# Standardizing and including some imports - convention?

Tags: django, model-view-controller, django-views, dry, conventions

I notice that I import many of the same imports into nearly every view (render_to_response, simplejson, HttpResponseRedirect, and a couple others).

It strikes me as WET to have these same few lines at the top of every view.

Is it conventional to create an include with these imports and include in many views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean something like:

```
# utils.py
import django.shortcuts
import simplejson
render = django.shortcuts.render_to_response
asjson = simplejson.loads
tojson = simplejson.dumps

# views.py
import utils

def myview ( request, ... ):
    # ...
    stuff = utils.asjson(some_presumable_json_formatted_data)
    # ...
    return utils.render(template_name, ...)
```

I have no idea if it's conventional, but I do that all the time. It's shorter to type, easier to maintain and just plain [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Note: it's obvious that some extra stuff will get imported in most of the files that use this auxialiary import module, and that might pollute your namespace. However, since you have control over both the `utils` module and local modules that import it, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I mean.  Also, you can do import django.shortcuts.render_to_response as render instead of the assignment.  I'm not clear on the problem with the namespace pollution - like if I wanted to use render for something else? :-)

Comment: You would get namespace pollution if you `from utils import *`. However, that's not likely, since it's so easy to just use `utils.rednder`. I know I can use the `import foo as bar` form, but I like the assignment :-)